# Round float numbers but not integer numbers in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this data:

```
number 
1
2
3
7.215115151215
2.5545158432
0
2
```

I would like it to be like this:

```
number
1
2
3
7.21
2.55
0
2
```

I have tried to use number format and round 2 but it always changes things like this:

```
number 
1.00 
2.00
3.00
7.21
2.55
0
2
```

Comment: number column is float

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to change your numbers format in `php` in the way that `1.23216` would be looking like `1.23` you should use `number_format()` function and use the `is_float()` to check if the number is of float type

Example:

```
$num=1.2355645;
$numcheck1=(is_float(+$num))?number_format($num, 2):$num; 
echo $numcheck1; //will display 1.23
```

On the other hand:

```
$num=8;
$numcheck2=(is_float(+$num))?number_format($num, 2):$num; 
echo $numcheck2; //will display 8
```

Comment: It's likely that those numbers are still strings, so you would need to coerce them into floats by using `is_float(+$num)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
echo (float)number_format($num, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you want your resultset being fetched this way from MySQL you can do

```sql
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.00' FROM ROUND(number, 2)) number
  FROM table_name
```

Outcome:

```
mysql> SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.00' FROM ROUND(number, 2)) number FROM table1;
+--------+
| number |
+--------+
| 1      |
| 2      |
| 3      |
| 7.22   |
| 2.55   |
| 0      |
| 2      |
+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Although it's a matter of presentation and you better be doing this in php.